# How to set image's click attribute in data-bind

Tags: knockout.js

View:

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">
   <img data-bind="attr: { onclick: PlaySounds }" src="/Images/audioGreen.png" alt="Pronounce word" title="Pronounce word" style="cursor: pointer" />
   <a data-bind="attr: { href: GoogleQuery }" target="_blank">
      <img src="/Images/googleIcon.png" alt="Google Search" title="Google Search" style="cursor: pointer" />
   </a>
</td>
```

Knockout View Model:

```
function DictionaryEntry() {
   var self = this;
   self.Simplified = ko.observable("");
   self.Traditional = ko.observable("");
   self.Phonetic = ko.observable("");
   self.Definition = ko.observable("");

   self.GoogleQuery = ko.computed(function () {
       return "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + self.Simplified();
   }, self);

   self.PlaySounds = ko.computed(function () {
       return "playSounds('" + self.Phonetic() + "')";
   }, self);
}
```

Info about "attr" binding: "http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html"

Error Details:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: ReferenceError: 'PlaySounds' is undefined;
>   Bindings value: attr: { onclick: PlaySounds }

Not sure where I am going wrong. If possible, binding directly without using the ko.computed values would be a bonus. A solution either way would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question... a bit late, but I hope it helps someone else:

What I did to get it working was using: `click: $root.PlaySounds` and have the function in my main ViewModel.. not the DictionaryEntry (child) model.. like this:

```
self.PlaySounds = function (entry) {
                playSounds(entry.Phonetic);
                return false;
            };
```

That worked nicely.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to use an `attr` binding to bind a function to a click, for this you should use the Knockout `click` binding:

```
<img data-bind="click: playSounds" src="/Images/audioGreen.png"
     alt="Pronounce word" title="Pronounce word" style="cursor: pointer" />
```

Comment: Hi Colin, I am aware of the click binding, but as far as I can see, it does not allow me to pass in a knockout variable, does it? What would be the syntax to pass in "Phonetic" from my viewModel, for example?

Comment: by the way, I just commented that one line out and can see I am getting the same error with biding the href for the Google Query link

Answer (score 0):

The binding you want is `click: function() { playSounds(Phonetic()) }`. If you want us to actually debug specific errors, please provide an example of your code (in jsfiddle, for example).

Comment: Thanks Michael, but this is not working either. I changed it like so: "<img data-bind="click: function() { playSounds(Phonetic()) }" src=", etc... and get this error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Function expected".. it breaks at this dynamic code: "function anonymous(sc) {
with(sc[1]) { with(sc[0]) { return ( { 'click': function() { playSounds(Phonetic()) } } ) }  } 
}". Also, I still have the "attr" binding issue with the 2nd value "GoogleQuery" which is just a string. This also throws a similar error. I'm completely confused now. :|

Comment: That sounds like it can't access the playSounds function. How is that function defined? It either needs to be part of your view model or defined globally.

Comment: It also could be because it can't access Phonetic. That would mean that your view model isn't accessible. Unfortunately, without seeing more of your code, I can't debug that for you.